# Maybe bad jasper report dependency in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, jasper-reports, vaadin

I'm developing my first application with vaadin and spring. I'm using also maven for dependency management. Now i have this trouble, when i try to add a the followed jasper report dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error

> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Alex.m2\repository\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\138\bcprov-jdk14-138.jar'

then i also try to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>138</version>
</dependency>
```

but doesn't work.
Where i wrong?

Comment: Do not add the transitive bouncycastle dependency yourself. Remove the  C:\Users\Alex.m2\repository\bouncycastle directory and mvn package

Comment: tanks for your comment, now works, but what had happened?